# Filtering more than one list item with "getElementsByTagName"?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, filter

How can I filter more than one list item with one checkbox? Thanks.

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.onload=function()
{
    document.getElementById('onclick').onclick=function()
    {
    var check=document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    lis=document.getElementsByTagName('li'),i=0;

for(var i;i<check.length,i<lis.length;i++)
    {
    lis[i].style.display='none';
    if(check[i].type=='checkbox')
        {
        if(check[i].checked==true)
        lis[i].style.display='';
        }}}}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form style="width:600px;">

<div style="width:600px">

<div style="float:right; width:200px;">
<li>Red</li>
<li>Black</li>
<li>Green</li>
<li>Yellow</li>
<li>Blue</li>
<li>White</li>

<br>
</div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox"/><label>Red</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox"/><label>Black</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox"/><label>Green</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox"/><label>Yellow</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox"/><label>Blue</label>
</div>
<input type="checkbox"/><label>White</label>
<br>
<br>


<input type="button" name="onclick" id="onclick" value="Submit">
<br>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you talking about making them vertically line up, like this? http://jsfiddle.net/wTLWE/

Comment: Nope, i just want to filter more than one list item at a time.

Comment: what do you mean by saying you want to "filter more than one item"? by observation your script hides all `li` elements where the corresponding checkbox is unchecked. what is supposed to happen? also, `li` elements are only valid as children of a list element like `ul`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can think of is to use the "id" attribute for the "li" tags and control its visibility by an event attribute from its relevant "input" tag (or from any input tag).

```
<script>
  function processme(id_chk, id_li){
        var li = document.getElementById(id_li)
        //1. Add more list elements here if required OR
        //2. do a getElementByTagName and negate li
        if (document.getElementById(id_chk).checked == true) li.style.visibility = ''
        else li.style.visibility = 'hidden'  
    }
</script>

<form style="width:600px;">

    <div style="width:600px">

        <div style="float:right; width:200px;">
            <li id="red_li">Red</li>
            <li id="black_li">Black</li>
            <li>Green</li>
            <li>Yellow</li>
            <li>Blue</li>
            <li>White</li>

            <br>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="red_chk" onclick="javascript:processme('red_chk', 'red_li')" /><label>Red</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="black_chk" onclick="javascript:processme('black_chk', 'black_li')" /><label>Black</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox"/><label>Green</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox"/><label>Yellow</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox"/><label>Blue</label>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox"/><label>White</label>
        <br>
        <br>


        <input type="button" name="onclick" id="onclick" value="Submit">
        <br>
    </div>
</form>​
```

ref: http://jsfiddle.net/TdCDW/